# Java classpath - Linux

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, classpath

I am trying to understand how classpath really works. After searching around the web this is where I have reached so far:

I have added

```
export CLASSPATH="/home/foo:/home/foo/Java_code/my_code"
```

at `/etc/environment`. I am running Ubuntu by the way.

Java finds the path and compiles without problem.

The problem is that if I change the CLASSPATH and then I do: `source /etc/environment`, the new CLASSPATH is not applied. It is applied if and only if I restart the system. For example if I delete the

```
export CLASSPATH="/home/foo:/home/foo/Java_code/my_code"
```

line, then I do source /etc/environment and I finally do `echo $CLASSPATH`, what I get is `/home/foo:/home/foo/Java_code/my_code`. I think I should get an empty line, shouldn't I?

Is there a way to apply the changes in PATH or CLASSPATH variables immediately without having to restart the system?

It might help you know that the /etc/environment file originally contained only the following line:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: How are you deleting the classpath?

Comment: why do you do all that stuff, what is your environment? /etc/environment is used to define environment variables for graphical applications. If you have graphics, you can use IDE. Why go to all this trouble with including your home folder+projects in classpath?

Comment: I am just trying to set CLASSPATH permanently in order to import packages from specific folders without having to define it each time I run javac.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should not put any paths that a local to your home directory in a system wide file. I would leave `/etc/environment` well alone, unless you provide some changes, that are necessary or beneficial to all users.
Put any changes to the CLASSPATH in your `.bashrc` in your home directory.

```
  CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/foo:/home/foo/Java_code/my_code
  export CLASSPATH
```

This way you can source it and any newly started bash will have the settings right at once.

Answer (score 5):

```
 export CLASSPATH=""
```

or better

```
 unset CLASSPATH
```

will delete an existing Classpath. There are multiple locations where you can set or unset the classpath - a missing entry will not unset it.

Answer (score 3):

When you remove

```
export CLASSPATH="/home/foo:/home/foo/Java_code/my_code"
```

line and then `source ...` it wouldn't remove the CLASSPATH because it has already been set. It doesn't clear the variables which have already been defined.

Comment: So the only way is to restart my system in order the new CLASSPATH to be applied?

Comment: You can put the `export CLASSPATH="/home/foo:/home/foo/Java_code/my_code"
` in your `.bashrc` file in your `~` directoy to set the variables each time you login. To unset the CLASSPATH variable, do `unset CLASSPATH`

Answer (score 2):

The `/etc/environment` file is not a normal shell script; it is not executed as a shell script when you boot or login into your system. So running it with `source /etc/environment` does not the same as when you normally boot your system.

See: [Ubuntu environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

> `/etc/environment` - This file is specifically meant for system-wide environment variable settings. **It is not a script file**, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line. Specifically, this file stores the system-wide locale and path settings.