# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver postgresql ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, jsp, tomcat, ubuntu

I have configured apache tomcat in ubuntu. I am using postgresql as database. I have downloaded `postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc3.jar` connector and set `CLASSPATH` as follows:

```
export CLASSPATH=/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/CMAS/WEB_INF/lib/postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc3.jar
```

I am using a JSP program to access Database values, code as follows:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java" import="java.sql.* " %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%
try {
String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/CMAS";
String username = "postgres";
String password = "postgres";

String myDataField = null;
String myQuery = "SELECT * FROM survey_details";
Connection myConnection = null;
PreparedStatement myPreparedStatement = null;
ResultSet myResultSet = null;
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
myPreparedStatement = myConnection.prepareStatement(myQuery);
myResultSet = myPreparedStatement.executeQuery();
if(myResultSet.next()){
out.print("herezz");
myDataField = myResultSet.getString("imei");
out.print(myDataField);
}
}
catch(Exception e){
out.print(e);
}

%>
```

I am getting an exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver". I understand its because of classpath. But how can I fix this?

Comment: @CraigRinger then what must be the reason for java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver Exception. I am new to ubuntu

Comment: Because you haven't installed the JDBC Driver *in tomcat*. http://www.google.com/search?q=tomcat+install+jdbc+driver, http://stackoverflow.com/q/13860024/398670

Comment: Try this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329650/java-classpath-linux

This will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The tomcat server does not have the postgresql JDBC driver in its resources.

Copy the postgresql-xxxx.Jar file to "apache-tomcat-xxxx\lib" folder.

(xxxx = whatever version you are using)