# Why am I not able to load the required libraries before running the JAR?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, jar, shared-libraries

I have created a graph project which needs JFree chart library.When I run the program it runs normally.But when I convert it into a JAR from Eclipse and run, it throws an exception saying there NoClassDefFoundErrors.Actually these classes are in the library.Does it mean that the JAR program doesn't have the library appended?Please help.

Comment: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm

Comment: @PM I zipped it and checked.Inside lib folder the referenced library is there.Please advice

Comment: Is it in `classpath`?

Comment: @user3680477 You zipped what ?

Comment: @PM77-1 In class path I have JRE system library and my project folder saying default class path.AM I doing it wrong? Should it be there in classpath? But I have added them to build path.Its just that its not visible in 'RunConfigurations->ClassPath'

Comment: @nos I made the JAR into ZIP and checked if the lib folder was there..

Comment: @PM77-1 here is my classpath:
Class-Path: . graph_lib/swtgraphics2d.jar graph_lib/jfreechart-1.0.17-
 experimental.jar graph_lib/jfreechart-1.0.17-swt.jar graph_lib/servle
 t.jar graph_lib/orsonpdf-1.3-eval.jar graph_lib/jfreechart-1.0.17.jar
  graph_lib/jcommon-1.0.21.jar graph_lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar graph_l
 ib/jfreesvg-1.4.jar graph_lib/junit-4.11.jar graph_lib/orsoncharts-1.
 0-eval.jar

Comment: @PM77-1 now it is running in Windows.When I run it on Linux I am getting the same error.Please help

Comment: Apparently you do not know what `classpath` is.  See if [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329650/java-classpath-linux) is of any help with you Linux situation.

Comment: @PM77-1 The class path of mine is having space as delimeter.This should work fine in both Windows and Linux.It is ';' that would cause a problem from Windows to Linux.But I don't have them.Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export it as an runnable jar. Also put the referenced libraries inside the src folder.Additionally if there are any unwanted jars which are not referenced remove them.When converting into runnable jar mark 2nd option in Library Handling.